# Java htmlunit: incompatible types for getPage?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, htmlunit

In my code it is giving an error when trying to use the getPage method. I'm not sure what the problem is, any ideas of perhaps where I should be looking?

I've tried adding the class under "found" to my import but it doesn't seem to exist. This is my first time posting a java problem so please let me know if more information is needed.

**The error:**
  java: incompatible types
  required: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage
  found:    com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.Page

**My code**

```
package com.buth.trabot;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import java.lang.Object;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.*;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;


/**
 * Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: Tyler
 * Date: 9/28/13
 * Time: 7:28 PM
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */
public class Main {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        final HtmlPage startPage = webClient.getPage("http://htmlunit.sf.net");
        assertEquals("HtmlUnit - Welcome to HtmlUnit", startPage.getTitleText());
    }
}
```

**My pom.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>MavenFirst</groupId>
    <artifactId>MavenFirst</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>htmlunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
            <version>1.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the return type of getPage is `com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.Page`.
Your variable is of type `com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage`.

You need to either change the type of your variable or add a cast.

Comment: Like this? final HtmlPage startPage = (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage("http://htmlunit.sf.net");

Comment: Yes. But note that if the returned page is not actually a `HtmlPage` object you will get a class-cast exception.

Comment: This worked. I needed to add "throws Exception" to the method and add (HtmlPage).

Comment: I'm having a similar problem but this answer is not correct.  Page is an interface that HtmlPage conforms too.  UnexpectedPage also implements the Page interface and is returned when HtmlUnit doesn't understand the header or it is nonexistent.  However I'm not clear on the rules for when UnexpectedPage is returned.

Comment: @nick If you can manage with just the `Page` interface methods then declare your variable as type `Page`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should be linking it this way:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
    <version>2.12</version>
</dependency>
```